# php/css/js: whitening img background?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have many images in my DB that have an off white background which bothers me...

is there a a way either try CSS or PHP or else to adjust them automatically?

it's literally a 5% off white, for worse photos i dont care and I will use photoshop

Answer (score 1):

PHP has GD lib available, you could whiten the whole image, or work on a far more complicated implementation to edit an image more selectively.

Check out the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).